# WPF- First line in TextBox gets "chopped", why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, textblock

I have this UserControl in WPF (C#), which is basically a dialog box. When you double click on it, it turns "editable".

The component is made up from a TextBlock which displays the text, and when you double click it, it 'disappears' it and brings upon a TextBox, where you can edit the text.

The UserControl must possess a property which defines the 'Line spacing' of the text (Like in Microsoft Word) from another UserControl that passes some parameters ranging from 0.5 to 3.0. (Same range values from Microsoft Word).

When you have a 'line spacing' of 1.5, for example, the text shows up like this:

[image]

...for BOTH the TextBox and the TextBlock (I bonded the Textblock.LineHeight Property with the TextBox.TextBlock.LineHeight Property, so they both share the same line spacing).

I can fix the text in the TextBlock with a simple padding based on the line spacing I capture from the other UserControl, so it shows the text on the same starting position regardless of the line spacing I apply (The first line must ALWAYS be on the same position, no matter which line spacing I am using).

THE PROBLEM:

If I apply the same 'solution' used for the TextBlock to the TextBox, it shows like this:

[image]

In this case, I applied a line spacing of 0.5 and the padding brought down the text, but the top part (The part that got 'swallowed' by the border) of said text is NOT visible (As if some kind of rectangle was in front of it). I tried moving the Padding and the Margin with the said results.

I cannot use RichTextBox, so solutions like that are off the table.

I tried with styles too, but still I cannot find an answer as to how make the top part of the first line come back.

I don't think any code is truly necessary for this, but, here it is:

- XAML:

  ```
      <StackPanel x:Name="TextContainer" MouseDown="changeTextBox" Margin="15" ClipToBounds="True">
          <TextBlock x:Name="TextDisplay" ClipToBounds="True"
                     ...
                     TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                     Padding="3,1,0,0" 
                     LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" />

              <TextBox x:Name="TextEdit" Background="{x:Null}"
                   ...
                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                   TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                   TextBlock.LineHeight="{Binding ElementName=TextDisplay, Path=LineHeight}">
              </TextBox>
      </StackPanel>
  ```
- SetSpacing Method (C#)

  ```
      private void setSpacing(DialogShapeCanvasElement x){

      double y = x.TextFontSpace;
      if (y < 0.5) y = 0.5;
      double w = y;

      FontFamily fontFamily = (FontFamily)x.GetValue(TextFontProperty);
      double fontDpiSize = (double)x.GetValue(TextFontSizeProperty);

      FontStyle fontStyle = (FontStyle)x.GetValue(TextFontStyleProperty);
      FontWeight fontWeight = (FontWeight)x.GetValue(TextFontWeightProperty);

      if (fontFamily == null) fontFamily = TextDisplay.FontFamily;

      double fontHeight = (fontDpiSize * fontFamily.LineSpacing);

      y = y * fontHeight;
      x.TextDisplay.LineHeight = Math.Ceiling(y / 1.8);

      if (w == 0.5)      { x.TextDisplay.Padding = new Thickness(3, 30, 0, 0); }
      else if (w == 1.0) { x.TextDisplay.Padding = new Thickness(3, 20, 0, 0); }
      else if (w == 1.5) { x.TextDisplay.Padding = new Thickness(3, 10, 0, 0); }
      else if (w == 2.0) { x.TextDisplay.Padding = new Thickness(3,  1, 0, 0); }

  }
  ```

Thanks in advance. Hope anyone can help me, I been searching for 3 days already and found no answer yet.

Comment: Can you not change the textbox to  a text area, as you would do on a datagrid editing template?

Comment: I can't seem to find a WPF Component called "TextArea" in WPF. The closest thing related to a TextArea is a Multiline TextBox, which I already implemented above.

Comment: What about "
            <TextBox x:Name="TextEdit"?

Comment: That's the component I'm trying 'fix'. The TextBox is the one in charge of managing text editing from user inputs. When I place the _TextBlock.LineHeight_ and the _TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy_, I can't seem to bring the first line down altogether without cropping it. This only happens when the _LineHeight_ is smaller than the _FontSize_ of the TextBlock.

Comment: Rather than switching controls, and then having to deal with their layout differences, why not just use a `TextBox` for both read/write. Change the `IsReadOnly` property when you want to enable editing, and change the style so that the ReadOnly appearance matches what you want.

Comment: If the line spacing is a problem, have you tried changing the font to one of the defaults like Arial or Tahoma (if it is, I apologise - I am not a designer - all fonts look the same to me).

Comment: @Mashton, the thing is the layout issue is in the TextBox itself, so using both TextBox would only double the problems.

AnthonyHorne, the thing is the TextBox/TextBlock component must be useful with different fonts and sizes. Either case, the issue is in the TextBox itself. As you can see in the pictures, there is a "margin" (so to speak) or a "Clip to bounds" property inside all the element mesh that composes a single TextBox. I'm looking for a way to remove that "Clip to bounds" property (If there is one) so the text doesn't show up "chopped".